How to get Locale Based data from Get_Questionnaires Method in Recruiting SOAP Request
We have a requirement to display Questionnaires Labels based on different Locales but SOAP request for the same is always returning the data in English Locale. Is there a way to retrieve data (Labels) in different Locales, where Locales can be a parameter to request.
Or if this is not feasible using SOAP request, then is there an alternate way to achieve the same?
Tried using SOAP Request Get_Questionnaires but it is always returning in English Language rather than different Locale/Language
